# How we could remove tags from data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a large database and a sample of the data are as follows:

```
data <- tibble(
    time = c(1,2,3,4),
    year = c("2000 (x", "2002", "2005 (b)","2004(z)"),
    temp = c("20", "30 M", "43 (N)", "60" ),
    year2 = c("1970", "1980(c)", "1990", "2000"))
```

As you can see from this small data, some data have a tag and I want to remove them across the database.

Here is the outcome of interest

```
  time year temp   year2
1    1 2000   20    1970
2    2 2002   30    1980
3    3 2005   43    1990
4    4 2004   60    2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `gsub` within `lapply` to remove the tags, e.g.,

```
type.convert(list2DF(lapply(data, function(x) gsub("\\D", "", x))), as.is = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
  time year temp year2
1    1 2000   20  1970
2    2 2002   30  1980
3    3 2005   43  1990
4    4 2004   60  2000
```

Comment: If the bracket is attached to the number, like this 4(mode), it does not remove it, Can we do better?

Comment: @user330 I got the same output as your desired one.

Comment: @user330 Do you have float numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by float, may I have an example? For example, Name are disaaperated

Comment: @user330 Something like `3.45`

Comment: No, I do not have, Names. some characters ,A,,,

Comment: Your code is very good, is it possible to fix it?

Comment: @user330 I don't know what happened to your real data since I can only see your post example

Comment: Slightly shorter version: `list2DF(lapply(data, function(x) as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", x))))`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract(STRING, PATTERN)` from [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org) to match only the numbers, in case its only numbers you are interested in:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  year = c("2012 (a)", "2020", "2030 (b)"),
  temp = c("20", "30 (TAG)", "48 (TAG)"),
  year2 = c("1912", "1920 (c)", "1930"))

data
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      id year     temp      year2   
#   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
# 1     1 2012 (a) 20        1912    
# 2     2 2020     30 (TAG)  1920 (c)
# 3     3 2030 (b) 48 (TAG)  1930 

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    year = str_extract(year, "[0-9]*"),
    temp = str_extract(temp, "[0-9]*"),
    year2 = str_extract(year2, "[0-9]*"))

data
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      id year  temp  year2
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 2012  20    1912 
# 2     2 2020  30    1920 
# 3     3 2030  48    1930
```

**Explanation:**
`str_extract()` returns the match of a regular expression ([one of many, many introductions](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-regular-expressions-with-r-df5e897ca432?gi=8123da6085ee)), in this case any amount of digits.

**Edit 1:**

using `across()` as suggested by @zx8754

```r
data <- data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~str_extract(.x, "[0-9]*")))
```

Comment: Sorry,  but It does not reflect the outcome of interest, As I said I have many columns with the different column names.

Comment: You could look into across to apply same function to multiple columns.

Comment: updated my answer to incorporate @zx8754's solution